# Why does importing an image crash the app for BunJS and NextJS?

Tags: image, next.js, jpeg, bun

I've an issue with BunJS + NextJS. I know, this JS runtime is in the initial phase but I wanted to test it due to operation speed. So I built the app with a template `bun create next bun`.

Next, I added a picture to the project and called it in `index.tsx`.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import dogImg from '../assets/dog.jpg'

<Image src={dogImg} alt={'test-image'} priority />
```

And here is where the problems began. I get an error:

```
Error loading page: .../app/bun/pages/index.tsx


error: Expected ";" but found ""
JFIFLExifII&
            8Happy dog smil
```

I tried to change picture, use  JSX tag, etc. For me it looks like BunJS doesn't support image files yet. The second thing I noticed is that BunJS doesn't work with SASS. I set up the same configuration as in another pure Next.js project.

Used at: `WSL, Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, BunJS 0.5.9, template v0.0.137 (package.json)`

What can I do more to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.